# HP Pavilion Slimline 400-214 Windows 10 has 12 GB RAM but is using less than 4 GB

Tags: windows-10, memory-usage

My HP Pavilion Slimline 400-214 Windows 10 has 12 GB RAM but is using less than 4 GB. I have double checked the Boot advanced options.  The max memory box is unchecked.  Here's what I'm seeing.  My computer never gets above 4 GB in used memory.  What else should I do?

[image: Task Manager Image]

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks good for a 12 GB computer with a relatively light load.

In the screenshot the memory manager has assigned only 2.2 GB as "In use" as that is all that can be effectively used. More would be wasted. But be sure to notice the value labeled as "Cached". This memory serves as a kind of system wide cache and contributes to overall system performance. "In use" and "Cached" together amount to 4.6 GB. With a larger workload this would be even higher.

The "Cached" value has 2 parts, "Modified" and "Standby". These are shown in individually in Resource Monitor. "Modified" is usually quite small and I will not go into it here.

"Standby" memory serves a dual role. It is memory that contains useful information but is not currently being used by any process. You may have noticed that when running an application for a second time it will start quicker than the first time. This is accomplished by keeping in memory the application executable and DLL files it was using. This memory is a part of the "Standby" value. It has other functions as well.

In addition to this role Standby memory is also part of available memory. Just like free memory it is available for the use of any application that needs it. As an ideal all of available memory would from the Standby value with no free memory at all. But on a lightly loaded system there is likely to a lot of  free memory, as is the case in the screenshot.

Within reasonable limits adding RAM will always improve performance. But there will always be a point of diminishing returns after which there will be little or no gain. That point is heavily dependent on the workload. From the screenshot the computer appears to be beyond that point, at least with the current workload.

The memory manager will always try to maintain a good balance between "In use" and "Available" memory, the goal being to maintain optimum performance for all running processes. This is a very complex process. On a lightly loaded system that balance will be easy to accomplish. On a more heavily loaded system it will have to work harder.

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like a problem. It is not using all of the memory because it does not have to.

Sometimes when you use the phone in little to low brightness it does not mean that there is something wrong with it. It will use it when there is heavy load and a requirement for it is there.

Comment: Agreed. You would have to worry if it where swapping to disk.